# Ruby on Rails: .constantize: wrong constant name error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using this:

```
4.times { |i| assert_not_equal("content#{i + 2}".constantize, object.first_content) }
```

and i have previously declared local variables

```
content1
content2
content3
content4
content5
```

the error I get

```
NameError: wrong constant name content2
```

Whot does this error mean? I'm pretty sure that I want content2 =\

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to call ruby constants with a big letter:

`Content2` instead of `content2`.

> A constant name starts with an uppercase letter followed by name characters. Class names and module names are constants, and follow the constant naming conventions. By convention, constant variables are normally spelled using uppercase letters and underscores throughout.

[Link](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html)

It should be noted though that there is no such thing as constant variables, but constant values.

Comment: interesting. is there a similar method to .that keeps casing? constantize

Comment: Sorry for the deletion of comments, I kept misunderstanding your question

Comment: like... right now it is capitalizing the string I give it. so, currently, .constantize turns "hello" into Hello.     Is there anything that will turn "hello" into hello. (preserves case)

Comment: If you want the value of the variable you can just use eval (but be careful of course)

Answer (score -1):

Can you please user eval("content#{i + 2}")

Note that eval is dangerous though :-)

Comment: When using eval we might do something like this: eval(user.name). If the user has entered "system('rm -rf /')" we might end up in removing the filesystem.

Comment: oh dear. wouldn't the system ask for permission before running that command?

Comment: What if user.name returns User.destroy_all :-)